# diskpart - How do select FAT32 CHS vs LBA

Tags: sd-card, diskpart

I'm dealing with a pretty old embedded device, and I have extracted and analyzed the SD card that it boots from: Master Boot Record partition ID = 0x0b, aka FAT32 with CHS Addressing.

When I try to format a new SD Card with diskpart:

```
format fs=fat32
```

I always end up with partition ID 0x0c, aka FAT32 with LBA Addressing. I tried boot with this but the embedded device is apparently not compatible with LBA.

Is there a different diskpart command for creating FAT32 with CHS addressing?

Comment: How large is partition? For 0B type partition, it has to be smaller than 8 GB and reside in it's entirety below 8 GB. If any of these conditions aren't met it requires LBA addressing -> OC type partition.

Comment: It's on a 2 GB card.

Comment: You could create the partition and use a disk editor and change OC to OB in partition table (offset 450 in LBA 0, assuming a single partition).

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Isn't that only changing the ID? I thought there were actual implementation differences as well (specifically with addressing).

Comment: It is only changing the ID. But there's no fundamental difference between a 0B and 0C partition from file system perspective AFAIK.